# Cannot find Dockpanel in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dockpanel

I installed VS2012 and wanted to create a Silverlight application using dockpanels. I have read "somewhere" that the dockpanel component must be separately installed but I cannot find the instructions anymore using Google. MAybe someone from stackexchange community can help and point me to the place where I can find how to add the dockpanel componenet to VS2012. Many thanks

Comment: I think you have to reference System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I found the answer inspired by this link http://procbits.com/2011/07/19/missing-dockpanel-add-dockpanel-for-silverlight-4-or-silverlight-5 . You have to install the Silverlight Toolkit 5 which can be downloaded from here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435

Answer (score 3):

Download the [Silverlight 4](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528) Toolkit. Install it. (Yes, this will work with Silverlight 5 beta)

Add a reference to "System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit". In Silverlight 5, you will need to navigate to the file: `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Bin\System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll`

Add the following attribute to your UserControl: `xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"`

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <tk:DockPanel>

        </tk:DockPanel>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Source:[missing-dockpanel-add-dockpanel-for-silverlight-4-or-silverlight-5](http://procbits.com/2011/07/19/missing-dockpanel-add-dockpanel-for-silverlight-4-or-silverlight-5)

Comment: the standard xml namespace declaration to use across the Silverlight Toolkit is `xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"`. (As defined in the System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit assembly using the the XmlnsDefinition and XmlnsPrefix attributes).   This way you don't need to add more namespace declarations if you use controls in different toolkit assemblies, like System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit